Operation similar to the extension of Euclidean algorithm
Given three real positive numbers $(a,b,c)$ we replace the largest number with its difference with the sum of the two other numbers (if the new number is still positive). For which triplets we eventually get a zero?
For example, if we start with numbers $(18,10,3)$ we will continue with $(5,10,3); (5,2,3); (0,2,3)$. However if we start with $(17,3,10)$ we get $(4,3,10);(4,3,3)$ and we can't do the next step.
I had started working backwards: on the last step we had $(x,y,x+y)$, so on the step before we had either $(x,y,2x+2y)$ or $(2x+2y,y,x+y)$ or $(x,2x+2y,x+y)$. I wrote down another step but didn't see the pattern in the coefficients for $x,y$.
Any help appreciated.

well, the gcd doesn't change.  I suggest wrting a program, all integer triples $x > y > z >0$   with $x$   up to some bound, ten to start. Simply having a count  of successes and failures (up to some bound)  would be progress

less repetition if you use triples with gcd 1.

What is the source of this problem?

Minor comment here, but do you mean to say real numbers or strictly integers? I see that you mean the numbers are all non-negative, and your examples are all integers. Also, Welcome to Math.SE!

@theREALyumdub all of the numbers are real in fact. however solving the problem for integers may have suggest us the idea behind real numbers

@Saxon Why are you considering an integer algorithm's application to real numbers (mind you, a number theory problem?) What is the source of this problem?

@theREALyumdub It is well-known that Euclid's algorithm works not only for integers, but for polynomials and in fact where we define division and residues. Euclid's algorithm also works for three numbers: $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$, so we first solve for $\gcd(a,b)$. I am interested if solving for three variables from the very beginning still gives us their GCD, that's how I got the operation. Though I quickly realized that the algorithm doesn't always work, but it definitely works if one of the numbers is $0$ because it's just Euclid's algorithm for integers. Hope I answered well.

@Saxon, yes I understsnd that, and Will Jagy also made this point since you said "euclidean" and he understood the algorithm. I think you did answer well, but it remains elusive to me whether you are looking at a discrete case or a real case. I think the two variable euclidean algorithm on real numbers can go forever in certain cases, think golden ratio.

It's much easier to answer the question you just asked (does this compute a euclidean algorithm for three numbers that preserves the gcd?) than it is to answer the OP (does a certain specific triple terminate the algorithm, that is hit zero?). This may be why you never got an answer yet. I will answer briefly.

It's become clear to me through the comments that the OP was asking about a gcd algorithm. I may just try and muck up an answer a couple of different ways, as I found this interesting but I was unable to directly answer the question of finding a specific criterion that makes a number hit zero under the algorithm I best understand to be discussed here.
I specifically considered the function, for $a \geq b \geq c$, where
$$\{a, b, c\} \mapsto \{b, c, a - b - c\}$$
Noting this could be out-of-order after an iteration of the function, we'll reorder the numbers on the image. Iterating this function gives the desired effect, but we would check that it would terminate if $ a < b + c$, so as not to produce any negative numbers.
$$\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}$$
However, the dichotomy that the algorithm terminates with $0$ or with the largest being too small is also false, there are convergent (infinite) sequences here too when the values are considered to be real.
A simple example is from the value
$$\{T^2, T, 1\}$$
where
$$T^3 - T^2 - T - 1 = 0$$
is the only real root of the equation, so that T is the Tribonacci constant.
Here, the definition of the constant means that the sequence of triples produced is a geometric sequence that limits to zero.
$$\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}$$
The part I think being commented on here is that the gcd of all three integers actually is preserved by the function, meaning we can take the GCD. This was commented by user Will Jagy and it's pretty clear that it does to the commenters and the OP, so I will move along with assuming there is a desire for integer values in the calculations, and that we want to preserve the GCD of three numbers.
Note that the gcd is NOT preserved pairwise. This is apparent from the examples originally given.
We can modify the original algorithm to use the following function:
$$ f(\{a, b, c\}) = \begin{cases} \{b, c, a - b - c\} & a > b + c \\ \{a, b - c, c\} & a \leq b + c \end{cases} $$
Where it's also implicitly assumed those sets reorder after the calculation so that $a \geq b \geq c$. I believe this algorithm will compute $\gcd(a, b, c)$ if the termination condition is taken to be that two numbers are zeroes.
There are likely many more algorithms that iterate a function to produce a GCD on Euclid's principle, but I've spent a lot of time on this problem now and should seek greener pastures. Hopefully the time I've spent will be enough for an upvote if nothing else.
